# Java mono call void method with arguments

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have the following method:

```
void save(User user);
```

And I call this method in this function:

```
userRepository.findById(id)
              .flatMap(user -> {
                   userRepository.save(user);

                   return Mono.just(userMapper.map(user));
              });
```

Is there a way that I can call the `save` method without the need to use a `flatMap`?

I tried the `then` but it does not accept lambdas?

Any other option?

Thanks

Comment: reactive java does usually not have `void` functions. We need more context, is `save` a blocking call to a database?

Comment: so what's wrong with flatMap here then?

Comment: @TheCornInspector if `save()` is `void` then it implies it'll block the thread servicing the `flatMap` until its work is done.

Comment: @AdamBickford Normally I could see that, but in this case I think OP just forgot to use Mono<Void> in his save method, since his findById() method returns a Mono.

Comment: @TheCornInspector If I return `Mono<Void>` instead how would the function would look like? I would still use the `flatMap`?

Answer (score -1):

`reactor.core.publisher.Mono` provides various methods which runs based upon need or signal.
Not sure why not wanted to use `flatMap`. You can use various other methods of `Mono` to call `repository.save(...)`. E.g.

- map() - takes lamda/Function object which provides T input and R return
- doOnNext - takes lamda/Consumer object which takes T
- doOnEach - takes lamda/Consumer object which takes T
- doOnSubscribe - takes lamda/Consumer object which takes T

These all methods evaluate when Mono will be subscribed.

Also not sure which repository you are using because most of the `Repository` (from Spring Data Reactive) returned object after persistence e.g.:

```
<S extends T> Mono<S> save(S entity)
```

If there is need to load an object from database update it and return it then below code can be consider as example:

```
fun update(id: Long, person: Person): Mono<Person> {
        return personRepository
            .findById(id)
            .map {it ->
                    p?.let {
                        it.name = p.name
                        it.password = p.password
                    }
                return@map it
                }.flatMap(personRepository::save)
    }
```